# Find all relevant partial derivatives to show the expression is true

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Let $z = f(x, y)$ be a function with continuous partial derivatives. Let $x = e^r\cos(\theta)$
and $y = e^r\sin(\theta)$. By finding all relevant partial derivatives and using the chain rule, show that $$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2=e^{-2r}\left[\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta}\right)^2\right]$$
First I found the $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, which I took to mean that I needed to to find $\frac{dz}{dr}+\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ because of the chain rule, so I got:
$$\frac{dx}{dr}+\frac{dx}{d\theta}=e^r \cos(\theta)-e^r \sin(\theta)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dr}+\frac{dy}{d\theta}=e^r \sin(\theta)+e^r \cos(\theta)$$
Then after squaring both equations I got  $2e^{2r}$, but how do I find the partial with respect to $x$ and $y$ when both variables are expressed in another set of variables?

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule

$$ 
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} =\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}
$$

and

$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} =\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}.
$$

Substitute the appropriate partial derivatives, use the binomial theorem to expand the squares and use Pythagoras' trig identity to simplify. This will yield the required result.